# How to concatenate column values with matching column values in another column inside a case statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to create hhID in my column based on values in NodeID. IF nodeID is empty, hhId should be a copy of UID, If not, then hhID should be a combination of all UIDs with the same values of nodeID.I have put dummy text here; 'Nepal is there'. However, for UID, 'JBGNARZ1', hhID should be JBGNARZ1, JRL0UUOI.

```
 SELECT UID,nodeID,
 CASE 
     WHEN  nodeID='' THEN UID
     else  'nepal is there'
 END AS hhID
 FROM housetable;
```

[image]

I have tried using following code, but it concatenates all UIDs with empty nodeID values in a single string.

```
SELECT n.UID,
GROUP_CONCAT(n.UID)  AS hhID
FROM housetable n
GROUP BY n.nodeID;
```

However, I need all UIDs intact in my first column. Could you please kindly help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_concat` to achieve this:

```
with your_table as (
  select 'A' AS UID, null as nodeID
  union select 'B' AS UID, 1 as nodeID
  union select 'C' AS UID, 2 as nodeID
  union select 'D' AS UID, 1 as nodeID
)
select 
  UID, 
  nodeID,
  case when nodeID is null then UID
  else (select group_concat(UID) 
        from your_table b 
        where b.nodeID = a.nodeID 
        group by nodeID)
  end as hhID
from your_table a
```

| UID | nodeID | hhID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A |  | A |
| B | 1 | B,D |
| C | 2 | C |
| D | 1 | B,D |

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5fcb952037329be62308673ce812fd05)

Comment: Your code works fine, however, f the UIDs are repetitive in the database, it throws repetitive UIDs in hhIDs. I tried using distinct but doesn't seem to work. Can you please help?

Comment: `group_concat(distinct UID)` should work

Comment: No problem, please mark the answer as correct so others know it works

Comment: This query has a correlated subquery in it, which is generally a bad thing for performance as the table contents increase.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming nodeID is null when blank, this should get you what you need:

```
select case when isnull(nodeID) then housetable.UID else c.b end
from housetable
left join (
  select nodeID as a, group_concat(distinct UID separator ', ') as b
  from housetable
  group by a
) as c on c.a = housetable.nodeID and instr(c.b, housetable.UID)
```